# Inserting variable values into strings that already contain quotes

Tags: bash, shell

Below is the contents of a script. I want to run the commands literally from this script, but i also want the variable values to be substituted. e.g For ddmmyy, i would put 300318 today.

```
"/data/product/current/analysis/TOR/elasticsearch/splitLog" "--indir" "/data/sta
ts/tor/${site}/data/${ddmmyy}/TOR/clustered_data/elasticsearch" "logout" "/data/
tmp/incr/${site}/${ddmmyy}/logs" "--analysisOut" "/data/stats/tor/${site}/analys
is/${ddmmyy}/enmlogs" "--site" "${site}" "--date" "${yyyymmdd}" "--maxfiles" "10
24" "--datadir" "/data/stats/tor/${site}/data/${ddmmyy}" "--incr" "/data/tmp/inc
r/${site}/${ddmmyy}/splitLog.inc" "--handlers" "CppSyncs"
```

Comment: Add a bunch of `read -p "message : " variable` commands before the one you posted, e.g. `read -p "logs date : " ddmmyy` for the `${ddmmyy}` variable

Comment: Or if it's enough for you, simply `export` the different variables before executing the script, e.g. `export ddmmyy=300318`

Comment: Use the command `$()` instead. For example, for your input; `"/data/stats/tor/${site}/data/${ddmmyy}/TOR/clustered_data/elasticsearch"`, try to use; `"/data/stats/tor/$(${site})/data/$(date "+%d%m%y")/TOR/clustered_data/elasticsearch"`